# Модель в модели. Nested forms ruby on rails ActiveAdmin

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Помогите пожалуйста. Через ресурс ActiveAdmin не сохраняется вложенная модель во вложенной модели в консоли, выдает Unpermitted parameter:. Соотвественно, данные остальных моделей успешно сохраняются.

В моем случае выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ситуация с кодом:

app/admin...

```
ActiveAdmin.register Landing do
permit_params
performances_attributes: [:id, :title, :name, :subtitle, :img],
time_performances_attributes: [:id, :time, :block]

form name: 'Название лендинга' do |f|

      inputs 'Блок программы форума' do
        f.inputs do
          f.has_many :performances, new_record: true, allow_destroy: true do |r|
            r.input :title
            r.input :name
            r.input :subtitle
            r.input :img
            r.has_many :time_performances, new_record: true, allow_destroy: true do |rr|
              rr.input :time
              rr.input :block

            end
          end
        end
      end
```

/db/migrate/...time_performance

```
class CreateTimePerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :time_performances do |t|
      t.string :time
      t.string :block
      t.belongs_to :landing
      t.belongs_to :performance

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

/models/performance...

```
class Performance < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :img, ImageUploader
    belongs_to :landing
    has_many :time_performances
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :time_performances
end
```

/models/time_performance...

```
class TimePerformance < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :landing
    belongs_to :performance
end
```

/models/landing

```
class Landing < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :performances
    has_many :time_performances
    accepts_nested_attributes_for
                                  :performances,
                                  :time_performances
```

[image: ActiveAdmin]

В обычной ситуации (контроллере), как понял, используют для передачи параметров на запись:

```
private 
def param
  атрибуты модели
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у кого нибудь возникнет такая ситуация уберите привязку к основной базе (Landing)

```
class TimePerformance < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :performance
end

class CreateTimePerformances < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :time_performances do |t|
      t.string :time
      t.string :block
      t.belongs_to :performance

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

В DSL вложенных инпутов вы используете `allow_destroy: true`, а значит позволяете пользователю удалять вложенные записи. Под капотом в этом случае используется скрытый инпут `:_destroy`, который отсылается на сервер наряду с обычными полями. И его тоже нужно помещать в `permit_params`.

В вашем конкретном примере нужно прописать:

```
permit_params performances_attributes: [:id, :title, :name, :subtitle, :img, :_destroy],
              time_performances_attributes: [:id, :time, :block, :_destroy]
```